# Search an Oracle database for tables with specific column names?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a large Oracle database with many tables.  Is there a way I can query or search to find if there are any tables with certain column names?

IE show me all tables that have the columns: `id, fname, lname, address`

Detail I forgot to add: I need to be able to search through different schemas.  The one I must use to connect doesn't own the tables I need to search through.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

To find all tables with a particular column:

```
select owner, table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'ID';
```

To find tables that have any or all of the 4 columns:

```
select owner, table_name, column_name
from all_tab_columns
where column_name in ('ID', 'FNAME', 'LNAME', 'ADDRESS');
```

To find tables that have all 4 columns (with none missing):

```
select owner, table_name
from all_tab_columns
where column_name in ('ID', 'FNAME', 'LNAME', 'ADDRESS')
group by owner, table_name
having count(*) = 4;
```

Comment: You should probably use DBA_TAB_COLUMNS instead of ALL_TAB_COLUMNS to do this search, in case the user you're logging in as doesn't have access to some tables.

Comment: True, but only if the user you are connected as has SELECT ANY TABLE privilege.

Comment: Add `column_name` + `like` if you're not sure of the exact name: `select owner, table_name, column_name from all_tab_columns where column_name like 'someField%';`

Comment: I have the same issue, and I have used  the answer select owner, table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'ID'; But if I do a select * from one of the resulted table_names the error is table or view does not exist @TonyAndrews

Comment: @AndreeaOnica all_tab_columns returns columns from tables in your own schema and others that you can access.  If a table returned is in a different schema, then unless there is a synonym for that table you need to prefix it e.g. `select * from otherschema.tablename;`. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 21):

TO search a column name use the below query if you know the column name accurately:

```
select owner,table_name from all_tab_columns where upper(column_name) =upper('keyword');
```

TO search a column name if you dont know the accurate column use below:

```
select owner,table_name from all_tab_columns where upper(column_name) like upper('%keyword%');
```

Comment: upper is important

Answer (score 13):

The data you want is in the "cols" meta-data table:

```
SELECT * FROM COLS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'id'
```

This one will give you a list of tables that have *all* of the columns you want:

```
select distinct
  C1.TABLE_NAME
from
  cols c1
  inner join
  cols c2
  on C1.TABLE_NAME = C2.TABLE_NAME
  inner join
  cols c3
  on C2.TABLE_NAME = C3.TABLE_NAME
  inner join
  cols c4
  on C3.TABLE_NAME = C4.TABLE_NAME  
  inner join
  tab t
  on T.TNAME = C1.TABLE_NAME
where T.TABTYPE = 'TABLE' --could be 'VIEW' if you wanted
  and upper(C1.COLUMN_NAME) like upper('%id%')
  and upper(C2.COLUMN_NAME) like upper('%fname%')
  and upper(C3.COLUMN_NAME) like upper('%lname%')
  and upper(C4.COLUMN_NAME) like upper('%address%')
```

To do this in a different schema, just specify the schema in front of the table, as in

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA1.COLS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%ID%';
```

If you want to combine the searches of many schemas into one output result, then you could do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  'SCHEMA1' AS SCHEMA_NAME
 ,TABLE_NAME
FROM SCHEMA1.COLS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%ID%'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
  'SCHEMA2' AS SCHEMA_NAME
 ,TABLE_NAME
FROM SCHEMA2.COLS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%ID%'
```

Comment: How do I use this to look at a different schema? (I forgot to mention that req in my original question)

Comment: Just prepend the schema name onto the front of each table name...i.e. myschema.c1. Obviously you must have select privileges on the other schem

Comment: `SELECT * FROM COLS` returns nothing from my schema.  I only have select privileges on the tables.  Would select not be enough to allow me to view it via COLS?

Comment: `select * from schema1.cols` gives me a `table or view does not exist` error.  Would that have to do with how the privileges are set up?

Comment: Yes, it would.  It seems like Tony Andrew's answer is probably better for your situation.  I had forgotten about the "all_tab_columns" view.

Comment: The code example underneath: "This one will give you a list of tables that have all of the columns you want:" was extremely helpful for me.  Ty!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one that we have saved off to findcol.sql so we can run it easily from within SQLPlus

```
set verify off
clear break
accept colnam prompt 'Enter Column Name (or part of): '
set wrap off
select distinct table_name, 
                column_name, 
                data_type || ' (' || 
                decode(data_type,'LONG',null,'LONG RAW',null,
                       'BLOB',null,'CLOB',null,'NUMBER',
                       decode(data_precision,null,to_char(data_length),
                              data_precision||','||data_scale
                             ), data_length
                      ) || ')' data_type
  from all_tab_columns
 where column_name like ('%' || upper('&colnam') || '%');
set verify on
```