# Query which will bring table names according column name

Tags: oracle, schema

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle column query or search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953239/oracle-column-query-or-search)

I need a query which will bring name of the tables that contains that column name in oracle.

**Example:** Lets say that I have `table1` with columns `(a,b)`, `table2` with columns `(b,c)` and `table3` with columns `(a,b,c,d)` so I need a know which tables contain `C` column so I need a query which will bring table names, how I can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try to select from `all_tab_columns`:

```
select table_name
from all_tab_columns 
where column_name = 'C' 
and table_name in ('table1','table2','table3') -- optional
and OWNER = 'owner'; -- optional
```

Comment: I edited the post, I hope it will be more helpful.