# How to find the name of a table based upon a column name and then access said table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a column name "CustomerIDClass" and I need to find the table it's associated with within an entire Oracle database.

I've run this to determine the owner and name of the table where this column name appears:

```
select * from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS 
where COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%CustomerIDClass%';
```

and I'm getting this response:
I don't have enough reputation to post the image, so here's the link: http://i.imgur.com/a7rcKoA.png

I have no idea how to access this (BIN$Csew==) table. When I try to use it as a table name I get errors or messages saying that no rows were returned.

My main goal here is to write a simple statement that lets me search the database for the "CustomerIDClass" and view the table that contains this column name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953239/oracle-column-query-or-search
I don't have much point to add it in comment. 
Hope this help.

Comment: `BIN$` tables are tables that have been dropped but are still in the recycle bin.  Are you really sure that you want to access a table that has been dropped?  That seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

This table is in the recycle bin. You have to issue `FLASHBACK TABLE "Customer1"."BIN$Csew==$0" TO BEFORE DROP` command, given you have the appropriate privileges.

Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9012.htm

Answer (score 0):

Do note that in oracle the column names are stored in capital but you are using mixed case in your like statement therefore the select clause will not return any result

Try the below
select * from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS 
where COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%CUSTOMERIDCLASS%';